# JavaScript split JSON-string by counting objects (without knowing how many there are)

Tags: javascript, json, split, count

I have multiple values in an JSON structure like this:

```
[{"Id":22,"Title":"München - Stockholm 31.01.2017 15:00"},{"Id":23,"Title":"Stockholm - München 01.02.2017 18:00"}]
```

I know how to split one of them:

```
var text = "[{\"Id\":22,\"Title\":\"München - Stockholm 31.01.2017 15:00\"}]";
console.log(JSON.parse(text)[0].Title.split(","));
```

But how can one split multiple elements?

This would work, but only because I specified that there are 2 items.

```
var text = "[{\"Id\":22,\"Title\":\"München - Stockholm 31.01.2017 15:00\"},{\"Id\":23,\"Title\":\"Stockholm - München 01.02.2017 18:00\"}]";

var count = Object.keys(text).length;
console.log(count);

for (var i=0; i < 2; i++){
    console.log(JSON.parse(text)[i].Title.split(","));
}
```

I wanted to count the objects and use `count` in the for loop, but the output is 115 and not 2. If I write `text[1]` the output would be 1, but that doesn't help me either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you splitting that `Title` string on commas, it doesn't contain any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once again, the first thing you need is `JSON.parse`:

```js
var text = "[{\"Id\":22,\"Title\":\"München - Stockholm 31.01.2017 15:00\"},{\"Id\":23,\"Title\":\"Stockholm - München 01.02.2017 18:00\"}]"
var json = JSON.parse(text)
var count = json.length

console.log(count)
```

Consider the fact that all array/object operations need actual arrays and objects. A string is an array but it is an array of characters.